# Using velostat instead of a force sensing resistor

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to make an input device that will communicate with a game. The device will be incorporated into a phone cover. I want the user to be able to squeeze the cover...similar to how you would squeeze a stress ball. I have made a stress ball with an FSR incorporated in it. What I did notice, however, was that sometimes the values from the FSR changed. Like on day 1, the range would be 100 to 1020 and then on another day it would only go to 500. I thought it was the battery supply that was responsible for this but the circuit had a 5v regulator component as well, so the input voltage was maintained at 5V.

Now that I am using a phone cover, it will be tough to incorporate an FSR as the FSR also has really weak legs and this might not make it very durable or resilient for daily usage.

So my question is : could I perhaps cover the phone cover in velostat and use it in a similar manner to an FSR? Or should I stick with the FSR and find a way to work around the aforementioned issues?

Comment: Maybe you can add a calibration in software to account for the changes.

Comment: @Aaron for the FSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with Velostat is somewhat poor.  I find that the force/resistance relationship is much more sensitive to the physical connection between the outside conductors that sandwich the sheet, almost going away if I used conductive adhesive to glue the sheet down.  The piezoresistive component is much smaller than you would think.

If you want to design your doohickey this way, try to get the interface between velostat and metallic element to vary reproducibly with pressure.

Comment: As an aside, sourcing velostat either involved paying big bucks for a tiny sheet, or buying industrial rolls -- until I found a company on etsy that specialized in serving people compelled to shield their environs from waves.  They sell the stuff in reasonable amounts for people to shield their windows.  The tin-foil hat community served me well.

Comment: @ Scott Seidman Thank you for your insights and yes, the tin foil community also pulls through

Comment: How exactly would one get the velostat and metallic element to vary reproducibly with pressure? Yes, I have seen that velostat is not that easily available. Do you personally think using an FSR would be better? Despite its inaccuracy and weak legs and annoyingly staunch shape? @Scott Seidman

Comment: I tried to do this for a student lab with mixed results.  When you start playing around constructing the things, you start finding ways to do it repeatably... jigs, templates, soldering technique, etc.  Results were variable. It worked just about well enough, in most cases, to behave semi-reliably, but I wasn't thrilled.  I abandoned the approach mostly because it took a lot of my time, replacing it with an FSR in a Jameco-supplied course pack.

Comment: I think the best I can do is say before you count on it, spend a few dollars and put together a few prototypes.  It might well be good enough.

Comment: Note that adafruit used to sell a custom FSR kit, but it's listed as discontinued.  All the links on the page are dead.  I imagine it was not a very successful product.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1917

Comment: I put tens of hours into construction of such sensors, opting to abandon the approach.  If you're only doing a few, the effort might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I also think that making a few prototypes would be useful. The FSR I used was an okay option, I just wasn't thrilled with the lack of diversity (in terms of design), that the FSR afforded. So I think I will experiment around and then see what the best option is. Thank you for all your tips :) @Scott Seidman